# How the get "Manager" property from ActiveDirectory with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I am using the "activedirectory" package to get User's information from the Active Directory but I need to get more the User's Manager information too...

The code the I use is:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var ad = new ActiveDirectory('ldap://mydomain.com', 'dc=mydomain, dc=com', 'dragon@mydomain.com', 'dragon');
var query = 'cn=JohnS';
ad.findUsers(query, true, function(err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if ((! users) || (users.length == 0)) console.log('No users found.');
  else {
    console.log('findUsers: '+JSON.stringify(users));
  }
});
```

And what I get in return is:

```
[
   {
      "dn": "CN=JohnS,OU=NorthWall,DC=mydomain,DC=com",
      "userPrincipalName": "JohnS@mydomain.com",
      "sAMAccountName": "JohnS",
      "whenCreated": "20160315093421.0Z",
      "pwdLastSet": "131123123123467132",
      "userAccountControl": "66048",
      "givenName": "JohnS",
      "cn": "JohnS",
      "displayName": "busterd",
      "groups": []
   }
]
```

I would like to get the **specific manager of the user** information too.

Thanks in advance,
Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the *manager* attribute [is not included](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory#findUser) in the output and you need to create your ActiveDirectory instance as

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(...,
             attributes: {
                 user: [ 'dn', 'userPrinicipalName', ..., 'manager' ]
             });
```

Note: if overriding the 'user' or 'group' attribute, you must specify ALL of the attributes you want, i.e. if you want to keep all attributes that are currently returned - include them in `user: [ ]`.

A manager attribute is typically has a DN value referred to another user and depends on your requirements, you might either need to parse it (e.g. to extract  sAMAccountName out of it) or call the findUser() method to get a full name and other attributes of the manager.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried this solution before but for some reason it didn't work so I thought that the problem was that "manager" wasn't an attribute.
After I saw your post I tried again and eventually I had some other problem(with the DN parameters)  and your answer made me confident in that solution that worked.

Comment: Glad it helped. To ensure what attributes/data your AD has, you could browse it with tools like LDAP Browser www.ldapadministrator.com